# Lock Screen & force relogin for Mac

Tags: bash, osx-mountain-lion

I am facing an issue regarding locking the screen after some period of inactivity in `MAC OS X 10.8.5`. To set the `idle time` & ask for password at `re-login`d I am using the following commands

`/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :idleTime 120" \/Users/MyUser/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.screensaver."System_MAC_Address".plist`

`defaults write /Users/MyUser/Library/Preferences/com.apple.screensaver.plist askForPassword -int 1`

the plist files are getting modified once the commands are executed, but the changes are not taking effect immediately, what I had to do next is to open `System Preferences -> Desktop and Screensaver` manually once for the changes to happen or I had to restart the system.

I need to know, is is there any way possible for the changes to take effect immediately without restart or manual intervention.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Did you try `killall Finder`?

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks for the solution, it has solved the problem to some extent, but I have to still restart if I create a new `user` just doing `killall Finder` alone is not helping.
askForPassword is also not taking effect immediately though the value is getting modified in `com.apple.screensaver.plist` for the respective user.

Comment: Your question doesn't mention creating any new users!!!

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes, of-course I didn't I got this just by luck though, I had created another user earlier but didn't change anything regarding screensaver. While executing my script by logged in to that user I got the thing. I have tested the same by creating another user but got the same issue. 
Please point me in the correct direction.